# Can I pass a div and its contents to another page

Tags: javascript

I have a clickable div generated from a loop. I am trying to set it up so that onclick it appends itself to another div on a different page. Is this possible. Here is what I have tried.

```
     userDiv.addEventListener("click",
            function () {
                var one = document.getElementById('userDiv');
                var two = document.getElementById('singleUser');
                two.appendChild(one);
                window.open("Createtask.html");
     }
```

**EDIT** here is all the code

```
   var theID;
    var theName;
    var thePhoto;
    var len = results.rows.length;
    console.log(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        theID = results.rows.item(i).id;
        console.log(theID);
        theName = results.rows.item(i).username;
        var htmlStr = theName;
        console.log(theName);
        thePhoto = results.rows.item(i).imagepath;
        console.log(thePhoto);

        var imageHold = new Image();
        imageHold.src = thePhoto;
        console.log("this is the src:" + imageHold.src);
        var userDiv = document.createElement("div"); //Create the div
        userDiv.innerHTML = htmlStr;
        userDiv.appendChild(imageHold);
        imageHold.width = 100;
        imageHold.height = 100;
        document.getElementById('showUsers').appendChild(userDiv); //append it to the document
        userDiv.style.display = 'block';


        identity = results.rows.item(i).username;
        userDiv.id = identity;
        console.log(identity);
        userDiv.addEventListener("click",

            function () {
                var w = window.open("Createtask.html");
                w.addEventListener("load", function(){
                  var one = document.getElementById('userDiv');
                  var two = w.document.getElementById('singleUser');
                  two.appendChild(one);
                });
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Possible but pointless...

Comment: What kind of question is that? Try it, and see what happens.

Comment: @Amberlamps *"... Here is what I have tried."* So it seems the OP has tried the code but could not get it to work.

Comment: It is possible, subject to cross-origin policies and stupid bugs ;-)

Comment: Each userDiv has an id generated by the user's name. I am trying to pass the div and then extract the name from it on the next page. Is this possible?

Comment: @Inkers now that's a different question. You can only pass strings during navigation.

Comment: What about extracting the name before passing it on? It is easy to pass strings around. GET params, POST params, cookies, localStorage...

Comment: I didn't think I could use any GET POST because it is a Phonegap project. I thought these were PHP

Answer (score 0):

You just only do it **directly** with the child window, which created from your current window.

Comment: Hi Trung, do you mean I should link to the page instead of opening new window?

Comment: Hi Inkers, you just only control the window that you opened from the code. You cannot control other windows via links :)

Comment: OK I'm super confused. Time to walk away and do a bit of reading I think.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I was looking for. This gives me a global var name which is directly related to the userDiv of the person.

```
     userDiv.id=theName;
        userDiv.onclick=(function() {
            window.location.href = 'Createtask.html';
            alert($(this).attr("id"));
            name= $(this).attr("id");
```